# Retrieve SVN repository list from within Java application

Tags: java, svn

I need the list of repositories from the SVN server and also I need the associated users connectd to particular repository using Java API or through SVN command.

I have got the code to get the details inside the repository, but I'm not able to get the repository list from server.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion does not provide any API or interface for getting the list of repositories from a server.  If you are using Apache, you could probably issue a GET request to the root of the SVN server and then screen scrape the results to get the list of repositories.

Another option would be to use Subversion Edge for your server.  It includes a full REST API for server management type things such as getting the list of repositories.  See:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/ApiDocs

I am not aware of any options that would work if you are using svn:// or svn+ssh:// protocols.

Comment: I am using ubersvn as my server which uses Apache.Is it possible to get the same from Active Directory

Comment: Active Directory does not have a list of your repositories.

Comment: Mark, my doubt is that the active directory consists of all data related to all the software's. So if the same is stored for ubersvn , it will be possible to retrieve the same, is that right?

Comment: There are java Api in SVNKIT which helps to get the data inside an repository. The same way is  there any  way to list the  repositoreis

Comment: The SVNKit API is simply recreating what the SVN API does in C.  It still has to talk to a Subversion server.  The Subversion server does not have any API to return the list of repositories.

Comment: re: Active Directory.  I never mentioned it in my response, so not sure what context you are using it.  Active Directory is Microsoft's LDAP directory.  It has your user accounts.  It has no knowledge of software installed on a server and has no knowledge of Subversion. As mentioned before, Subversion Edge provides an API for managing the server and retrieving list of repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/):

> SVNKit is a pure Java toolkit - it implements all Subversion features and provides APIs to work with Subversion working copies, access and manipulate Subversion repositories - everything within your Java application.

Comment: Thank u phineas I had gone through the same...as I said in my question  it helps me to get the details of an repository, not the repository list from the server.